# Как в input type='radio', дать значение при отправке формы в php

Tags: php, html, html5

Мне нужно задать значение input и получить данные из них с помощью php, код

```
        <form action="/case/knife_case.php" method="get"  class="factor_case">
        <div class="factor_align">
            <input id="1x" name="factor1" type="radio">
            <label style="--i:1s" class="factor_label" for="1x">1x</label>
            <input id="2x" name="factor2" type="radio">
            <label style="--i:2s" class="factor_label" for="2x">2x</label>
            <input id="3x" name="factor3" type="radio">

$amount = $_GET['factor1'];
echo $amount;
```

Даже если я ставлю value не работает

```
    <form action="/case/knife_case.php" method="get"  class="factor_case">
        <div class="factor_align">
            <input value="sadas" id="1x" name="factor1" type="radio">
            <label style="--i:1s" class="factor_label" for="1x">1x</label>
$amount = $_GET['factor1'];
if (isset($amount)) {
    echo 'good';
} else {
    echo 'none';
}
```

выводит просто none [image: Вот]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542576/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-radio-button-in-php

Comment: А проблема в чëм?

Comment: В том что с помощью value не могу передать значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тега input, есть артибут "value" для хранения значения.

```
<form action="/case/knife_case.php" method="get"  class="factor_case">
<div class="factor_align">
    <input id="1x" name="factor1" type="radio" value="test-value">
    <label style="--i:1s" class="factor_label" for="1x">1x</label>
    <input id="2x" name="factor2" type="radio" value="test-value2">
    <label style="--i:2s" class="factor_label" for="2x">2x</label>
    <input id="3x" name="factor3" type="radio" value="test-value3">
</div>

/* в файле knife_case.php */
$testValue1 = $_GET['factor1']; // test-value
$testValue2 = $_GET['factor2']; // test-value2
$testValue3 = $_GET['factor3']; // test-value3
```

Comment: Я уже так пробовал                 <input id="1x" name="factor1" value="fsdgjfh" type="radio">
                <label style="--i:1s" class="factor_label" for="1x">1x</label>

    $amount = $_POST['factor1'];
    if (isset($amount)) {
        echo 'hello';
    } else {
        echo 'none';
    }

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите в чём дело

Comment: Вы хотите передать значение нажатой кнопки (радио батон), правильно ведь? А куда вы хотите передать? На ту же страницу (где сами кнопки)? или на страницу knife_case.php? или это она и есть?
Опишите подробнее задачу.

Comment: Это она и есть, если есть возможность я могу скинуть ссылку на гитхаб и вы посмотрите и скажите как исправить это. Задача  такова мне нужно чтобы код выполнялся столько раз сколько я выбрал, но мне осталось только получить значения из этих input'ов.
 Вот ссылка на гит хаб там только основные файлы https://github.com/David-Meyster/cod.git .

Если будут вопросы по коду можете задавать и я постараюсь вскоре на них ответить

Comment: Ну что? Просмотрели?

Comment: Зачем такую задачу вообще на PHP делать? Там ведь перезагрузка страницы будет. 
В гитхабе <input type="submit" /> не вижу, форма не отправляется.
Напишите мне в телеграм https://t.me/Diss_mind.